# Difference between proto link and Object.create

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I want to know the difference between `__proto__`  and `Object.create` method. Take this example:

```
var ob1 = {a:1};
var ob2 = Object.create(ob1);

ob2.__proto__ === ob1; // TRUE
```

This implies Object.create method creates a new object and sets `__proto__` link to the object received as parameter.
Why don't we directly use `__proto__` link instead of using create method ?

Comment: 1. `__proto__` is non standard. 2). `Object.create` can accept the second parameter which can be useful.

Comment: One other difference worth noting is that `__proto__` allows you to set the prototype of an existing object to a different prototype, whereas with standard Javascript (even in ECMAScript 5), it's only possible to *get* the prototype (with `Object.getPrototypeOf`), not to *set* it.

Comment: What can we pass as second parameter ?

Comment: @blunderboy: You can read about it in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create.

Comment: @MattB.Nice point mentioned. Thanks

Comment: This library contains a nice shim to make the second parameter of `Object.create` fall back gracefully for older browsers: https://github.com/cujojs/poly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__proto__` is nonstandard and won't be supported everywhere.  `Object.create` is part of the official spec and should be supported by every environment going forward.

It also is implemented differently in different places.

From [Effective Javascript](http://effectivejs.com/):

> Environments differ for example, on the treatment of objects with a
>   null prototype.  In some environments, `__proto__` is inherited from
>   Object.prototype, so an object with a null prototype has no special
>   `__proto__` property

Moving forward the accepted way  to create objects and implement inheritance is the `Object.create` function, and if you do need to access the prototype, you'll want to use `Object.getPrototypeOf`  These functions are standardized and should work the same in all modern environments

Comment: "Create" term calls for confusion. I thought it is creating a new object and copying its properties but now I get it. Thanks :)

Comment: `Object.create` DOES create a new object.  The first argument is the new prototype, the second lets you copy properties.  See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: `__proto__` is now part of the ES6 standard:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__

Answer (score 3):

> Why don't we directly use proto link instead of using create method ?

Because `__proto__` is a **non-standard**  property and therefore not necessarily available in every browser.

However it seemed to be considered for [ES.next](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aspecification_drafts). More info: [MDN - `__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Comment: `__proto__` is now part of the standard: 
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__

Comment: @John: Yes and no. It's in Annex B, which says *"This annex describes various legacy features and other characteristics of web browser based ECMAScript implementations. All of the language features and behaviours specified in this annex have one or more undesirable characteristics and in the absence of legacy usage would be removed from this specification."* and *"These features are not considered part of the core ECMAScript language. Programmers should not use or assume the existence of these features and behaviours when writing new ECMAScript code."*

Comment: But before that it says:
The ECMAScript language syntax and semantics defined in this annex are __required__ when the ECMAScript host is a web browser.

Comment: Then I guess we can say that it will most likely work in browsers, but not necessarily in other environments. It should still be avoided.

Comment: Asking for folks not to use it is really wishful thinking on the committees part as the reality is that it is available and isn't going anywhere (unlike `with` and several other features).   `__proto__` isn't particularly useful when Object.create is available but there isn't any other reason to avoid it if it solves a problem that you have.